# Show starred posts on chat in chronological order

Tags: feature-request, sorting, chat-stars

Sometime recently a change was made to chat to show posts 'starred by me' in order of the number of stars.  From time to time I have occasion to star posts in a chat room for reference, and having this sort order makes it much harder to find the posts.

Could we please have an option to sort starred posts by forward/reverse chronological order (if this option is still available, it's not obvious) as well as by the number of stars on the post.

An option to sort by poster is probably also useful.